# positive output aand variables nnet-model r

Tags: r, nnet

Can anyone tell me how to constrain the output and selected variables of a neural network such that the influence of a charateristic is positive using the function nnet in R. I Have a database (real estate) with numerical (surface, price) and categorial values (parking Y/N, areacode, ectera). The output of the model is the price. The thing is that the model currently estimates that in a few areacodes the homes with a parking spot are less worth than the homes without a parking spot. I would like to constrain the output (Price) so that in each areacode, the influence of a parking spot on the price is positive. Ofcourse a really small house with parking spot can still be cheaper than a big house without a parking spot.

example data (of 80.000 observations):

```
Price   Surface Parking Y   Areacode 1  Areacode 2  Areacode 3
100000  100     0           1           0           0
110000  99      1           0           1           0
200000  110     0           0           0           1
150000  130     0           0           1           0
190000  130     1           0           0           1
```

(thanks for putting the table in a decent format)

I had this modelled in  R using nnet.

```
model = nnet(Price~  . , data=data6, MaxNWts=2500, size=12, skip=TRUE, linout=TRUE, decay=0.025, na.action=na.omit)
```

I used nnet because I hope to find different values for parking spots per area code. If there is a beter way for this please let us know.

Im using RStudio Version 0.98.976 on windows XP (yes i know;)

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: Do you mean with parking is costing less than with *out* parking? This sentence is not clear: "the homes with a parking spot are less worth then with a parking spot. "

Comment: Do you want to impose a constraint while learning the model that output (Price) > 0 for all input instances? Or does the output (Price) need to be constrained such that in each areacode, any house with parking should price more than any house without parking? These two are different constraints.